# can't apply the patch inside the directory

Tags: networking, mercurial

We are trying to install VANET patch file on ns3.15. According to the procedure, we create a clone from the ns-3.15 repository:

```
hg clone http://code.nsnam.org/ns-3.15
```

then unpack the patch inside the ns-3.15 directory. Then we try to apply the patch inside the ns-3.15 directory with the following command:

```
hg import --no-commit ns3-highway-may10.patch
```

But we got the following error message:

```
abort: no repository found in '/home/chinmoy/tarballs/ns-allinone-3.7.1' (.hg not found)!
```

what should I do? please help.

Comment: Are you sure you are in `ns-3.15` directory when applying patch? Mercurial states that you're in `/home/chinmoy/tarballs/ns-allinone-3.7.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the clone did not work, or the folder from where you typed in the ***hg import*** is not the same as when issuing the ***hg clone*** the first time.

The .hg folder (not found) is created during the clone operation, it is where Mercurial places the repository information. When applying the patch, if you do not specify the repository where the patch is to be applied, it uses the current folder, hence the abort error.

You need to copy the patch exactly where you were when issuing the ***hg clone***, and stay in the same place to do the ***hg import***. You can add the *--repository* option followed by the repo's folder, if you really need to issue the command from somewhere else.